# ServiceWorker で特定のファイルをキャッシュから削除したい

Tags: javascript, html, safari

サイトをPWA化するために ServiceWorker を使用しています。
キャッシュ指定しているファイルを修正した際にそのファイルだけキャッシュからではなく、サーバーから読み込んで再度キャッシュに取り込みたいのですが方法が分かりません。
下記のサイト等で追加するメソッド(cache.put)は分かったのですが、削除する方法が分かりません。ServiceWorker自体をdeleteすると他のファイルまで再読み込みする事になって処理が遅くなるので指定したファイルだけにしたいのです。
そもそも考え方が違っているのかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。
[Service Workerでキャッシュハンドリング (基礎編)](https://blog.ohoshi.me/blog/service-worker)

Comment: 参照している記事の中に記述されている`caches.delete(key)`を使えば良いのでは？ 他にはこんな記事も。[Cache.delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete), [Remove a specific file from service worker cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61241892/9014308), [Service-worker force update of new assets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33262385/9014308), [Service Worker updates, but old file is still cached](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59725245/9014308), [Service Worker: how to update the cache when files changed on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30523843/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。.deleteはServiceWorkerのバージョンセットを全て削除するものと勘違いしておりました。